# How to force scale in square by use React Rnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have and case to create QRCode,i use https://github.com/bokuweb/react-rnd
to drag and drop and resize QRCode inside background canvas.
I want to force user just scale this QRCode in square type.
How can i do that with https://github.com/bokuweb/react-rnd?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<Rnd
  size={{ width: this.state.width,  height: this.state.height }}
  position={{ x: this.state.x, y: this.state.y }}
  onDragStop={(e, d) => { this.setState({ x: d.x, y: d.y }) }}
  onResize={(e, direction, ref, delta, position) => {
    this.setState({
      width: ref.offsetWidth,
      height: ref.offsetHeight,
      ...position,
    });
  }}
>
  001
</Rnd>
```

In the JavaScript code above it has `onResize` which seems to imply that you can resize the QR code your working on with the correct aspect ratio.

```
    lockAspectRatioExtraHeight?: number;
The lockAspectRatioExtraHeight property enables a resizable component to 
maintain an aspect ratio plus extra height. 
For instance, a video could be displayed 16:9 with a 50px header bar. If 
omitted, set 0
```

My advice would be to, watch videos, learn how the JavaScript plugin works, then start implementing it into your website!

Comment: No need to be condescending.

Comment: this one just resize element in rectangle,haven't force resize in square yet.

Comment: thanks Pratt for the edit, definitely didn't wanna come off offensive in any way possible. kid Nguyen the only other reason i can see why its resizing the rectangle and not the square is maybe because you haven't declared a variable to the id of the square in JavaScript.